# Apollo Server Federation with graphql-shield

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-federation, graphql-shield

I'm using `graphql-shield` to protect a `subgraph`.

```
const isAuthenticated = rule({ cache: 'contextual' })(async (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
  return ctx.isAuthenticated
})

const permissions = shield({
  Query: {
    '*': and(isAuthenticated)
  },
  Mutation: {
    '*': and(isAuthenticated)
  }
})

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: applyMiddleware(buildSubgraphSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }]), permissions),
    introspection: global.configuration.ENVIRONMENT === 'development'
})
```

And in my build process, I'm using `rover CLI` to update the`supergraph schema` in Apollo Studio:

```
rover subgraph introspect http://localhost/graphql | rover subgraph publish super-graph@development --routing-url http://localhost/graphql --schema - --name persons
```

The `rover` update fails because the permission shield throws a `Not Authorised!` error.

How do I protect the `subgraph` with `graphql-shield` and also permit `SubgraphIntrospectQuery` operation?

I understand it is possible to add a bearer token to the rover introspect command:

```
rover subgraph introspect http://localhost/graphql --header "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

However, there is no way for me to generate an access token during the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the scope of my authentication.

Instead of authenticating all "*"

```
const permissions = shield({
  Query: {
    '*': and(isAuthenticated)
  },
  Mutation: {
    '*': and(isAuthenticated)
  }
})
```

I change to authenticating individual operations:

```
const permissions = shield({
  Query: {
    'user': and(isAuthenticated),
    'users': and(isAuthenticated)
    ....
  },
  Mutation: {
    'createUser': and(isAuthenticated),
    'updateUser': and(isAuthenticated)
    ....
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try allowing the following branches:

```
export const permissions = shield({
    Query: {
        _service: allow,
    },
    _Service: {
        sdl: allow
    }
},{
    fallbackRule: deny,
    allowExternalErrors: true,
    ...
});
```

When Apollo performs the introspection, it uses these two branches initially. Also note the "allowExternalErrors" flag. When encountering an error, graphql-shield absorbs them, which can hide issues which you are trying to debug. This *might* also be a problem, although your code seems fine otherwise.

Apollo also uses "Query._entities", "Query._service", "_Entity.*", "_Service.*", "_Any.*" but I haven't found this to be used by the initial introspection.

You mentioned that you can't generate a token for your build process but it is probably a good idea to protect these endpoints rather than use allow.

Comment: Mods, don't delete this answer unless you can guarentee it is a duplicate problem. The solution for two issues might be similar, which you should know. Plus you could at least let OP see it first, so he actually gets help, since it fulfils the entire purpose of this website

Answer (score 0):

There is answer.
Good luck:)).

```
/**
 */
export const permissions = shield(
  {
    Query: {
      "*": deny,
      _service: allow,

      ...,
    },
    Mutation: {
      "*": deny,

      ...,
    },
  },
  {
    fallbackRule: allow,
  },
)
```

https://github.com/dimatill/graphql-shield/issues/211#issuecomment-450636577